# NavigationStack make my dimiss button skip second View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

"I have three views: OneView, TwoView, and ThreeView. 
I can navigate between them without any issues. However, when I press the dismiss button in ThreeView, it jumps back to OneView. 
***But if I use NavigationView, there are no problems at all.***" i want from ThreeView to TwoView to OneView
or just me wrong how to use NavigationStack?

```
import SwiftUI

struct OneView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State private var move = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("One View")
                
                Button(action :{
                    move = true
                }) {
                    Text("Move")
                }
                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $move) {
                    TwoView()
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    Button(action: {
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }) {
                        Circle()
                            .foregroundColor(Color("bgButtonBack"))
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                            .overlay(
                                Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
                            )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct TwoView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @State private var move = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Two View")
                
                Button(action :{
                    move = true
                }) {
                    Text("Move")
                }
                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $move) {
                    ThreeView()
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    Button(action: {
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }) {
                        Circle()
                            .foregroundColor(Color("bgButtonBack"))
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                            .overlay(
                                Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
                            )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct ThreeView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @State private var move = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Three View")
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    Button(action: {
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }) {
                        Circle()
                            .foregroundColor(Color("bgButtonBack"))
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                            .overlay(
                                Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
                            )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

*NavigationStack no need to apply in each view just apply on 1 view.

Comment: `presentationMode` is deprecated. See joshuakcockrell's answer in the dupe target.

Comment: .navigationBarItems its deprecated its why i want use toolbar.

Comment: That's not the point... The point is `presentationMode` is deprecated. Use `dismiss` instead.

Comment: its same, its skip second view, and im using @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

Comment: Ah, upon rereading the code, you wrapped all three views with `NavigationStack`. How about removing it from `TwoView` and `ThreeView`?

Comment: if i remove that how TwoView move to ThreeView.

Comment: How about *trying* it? If it still doesn't work, please [edit] your question with your new code and describe what's wrong.

Comment: **its good now** NavigationStack no need apply on twoview and threeview. thanks @Sweeper